Multiplexing RF antennas to single NFC reader
I am planning on creating a gameboard which uses NFC to read and write data to figurines on the tiles. So far my research has brought me a lot of info but nothing to really piece it together. For my system it will be a micro, connected to a reader chip either the PN532 or the ST25R3911B. The antenna pins will be connected to a multiplexer to add on antennas to each square which will be printed on PCBs.
How should I go about this process and is there anything I am missing?
What kind of things to look out for with the antenna system?
I am not entirely sure how the multiplexer will impact the signal from each antenna and or the reader itself.

What did you design so far? Can you post schematics?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

start by reading the datasheets, for ease of multiplexing I recommend you choose the part that works with a two wire antenna
